# Transactional management with spring, hibernate and java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a class say `doSomething`. It's `@Transactional` annotated.
It has 3 methods `parent`, `child1` & `child2`.
methods `child1` and `child2` are also annotated separately with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.
The `parent` method calls `child1` first and then calls `child2`.
`child1` calls Dao method for saving some info.
When i run `parent` method, `child1` doesn't commit after finishing itself.
It commits after the `parent` method finishes.
Can you please explain this behavior as i was under an impression that when we say `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` it created a separate transaction, so it should commit changes that are taking place under this new transaction when this transaction finishes.

I was able to achieve this behavior when i annotated my Dao method with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` which was being called from `child1` for saving some info.

Also, I would like to know how the @Transactional annotation exactly works.

Comment: Spring uses a proxy based approach to AOP. So only method calls INTO the objects will be intercepted. Internal method calls don't pass through the proxy and nothing is thus intercepted.

Comment: You can also use aspectj based aop (not the default) which will support this.

Comment: I believe that you should read [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) on  `@Transactional`. Also the default propagation `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` is fine for the most cases, why did you chose `REQUIRES_NEW`?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov i chose Requires_new as i wanted that piece of code to be committed immedietley whrn that particular method ends.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure the methods inside same service class, commit changes when the finish?
i.e when child1 finishes it should persist all the changes immediately, same with child2.

Comment: I have a method, which first saves some info in DB, then send a textMessage to a queue. What i want to do is have the DB changes persisted before i send the message to queue.
i have a generic dao save method, which saves data for me.

Comment: You can avoid using transactional annotation for opening transactions  at all and guarantee that there is no transaction  outside by transactional with propagation NEVER(to assure that there is no current logical transaction) , and then use Spring transaction template class with default propagation inside that method..